# If the guests had ordered food

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense, conditional-constructions, subordinate-clauses

If I am a manager of restaurant, and I am keeping logs, can I write down something that happened in the past:

***If the guests had ordered some food, normally they would wait for 20 minutes***

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's not clear what your actual question is.

Comment: @moyeea We need more [details, please!](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/439/37009) Without them, unfortunately, your question may be closed. Please use the [edit] link to tell us what you don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

For you log, you could say

> If the guests ordered food, they would normally wait for 20 minutes, *otherwise they might only wait 10 mins.*

But it might be more clear to write in your log

> Once the guests order food, they normally wait for 20 mins.
>   After ordering food, the guests normally wait for 20 mins.

By using "If... had ordered" it suggests the possibility that the guests may not have ordered food and I am assuming in your log you are recording what actually *did happen* as opposed to a theoretical *what might happen*.

Answer (score 0):

If the guests **had ordered** some food, normally, they **would have waited** [would've waited] for 20 minutes. [**IF clause with past perfect +  past conditional in the second]**.

The whole thing is in the past.

Likely to occur: If the guest **order** food, normally, they **will wait** [they'll ] for 20 minutes [present tense in the IF clause, simple future in the second: What will happen if you use the present tense.

Not likely, also called condition contrary to fact:

If the guests **ordered** food, normally, they **would wait** for 20 minutes. [If clause in simple past, second clause in the conditional.]

That's how you do it. I suggest you practice with other sentences to get the hang of it. The only tricky part is the irregular verbs.

If we went, we'd see them. If we'd gone, we'd have seen them. [NOTE: I have also provided some of the contracted forms.